# Finding key with minimum value in OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to find the key whose value is the lowest in the ordered dictionary but only when it is True for the position in my_list.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_list = [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,]

my_lookup = OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 9), ('c', 4), ('d', 7),  
                         ('e', 3), ('f', 0), ('g', -5), ('h', 9)])
```

I know how to do it with a for loop like

```
mins=[]
i=0
for item in my_lookup.items():
    if my_list[i]:
        mins.append(item)
    i+=1
print min(mins,key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
```

prints

```
a
```

because a is lowest that is also True in my_list.

This works but it is long and I want to know how to do it with comprehensions or one line?

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) with key to `min` being `get` method,

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> min(compress(my_lookup, my_list), key=my_lookup.get)
a
```

Comment: +1, because this is I believe a perfect way of using the standard Python tools: this solution does the job precisely, without any cruft, and in a very compact and legible way.

Answer (score 3):

You can also combine generator expression and `min`:

```
>>> min(((value, key) for ((key, value), flag) in zip(my_lookup.iteritems(), my_list) if flag))[1]
'a'
```

Comment: This is really suboptimal: there is really no need to find first the selected *pair* and then the minimum *pair* just to later only keep its first element. Jared's solution shows why.

Comment: @EOL I don't think you are right. `zip` in Python 3.x returns iterator (in Python 2 `izip` should be used). Then this solution really forms tuples, but is is highly efficiently implemented in Python (the tuple is reused internally). Jared's solution use dictionary lookups, which despite having `O(1)` complexity have some overhead. If I see in the code with `compress` I will have to search what it does (because `compress` is not commonly used in Python). But if I see this solution with generator, I will understand at once what it does.

Comment: @EOL One more thing. Downvotes on Stackoverflow are for downright wrong answers. If you don't like a solution, it is no reason to downvote it.

Comment: I agree that `compress` is not commonly used, however I would argue that it is easy to look it up, and this has the advantage of adding yet another useful tool to one's Python toolbox. Furthermore, I must say that I find this solution definitely harder to read than Jared's, as it involves more steps, and also keeps information around that is not needed (a pair key-value when only a key is needed). By the way, it would help a little if you replaced the `(key, value)` tuples by a simple `item`, as there is no need to unpack the result into two variables).

Comment: PS: I do not encourage using variables that are redundant (your `value` is redundant since we already have `my_lookup` and `key`, so that `value = my_lookup[key]`), so I do think that there is something wrong with this approach, in addition to it being harder for me to understand than Jared's direct solution. I removed my downvote, though. :)

Comment: @EOL By the way, you are right. My solution turned out to be 2 times slower. See: http://ideone.com/L2cnke But it has noting to do with using `compressed` (because `f3` is as efficient as `f1`). But it turns out that packing into tuple and later unpacking is slower (even though tuples is reused in CPython) than making dictionary lookups.

Comment: @EOL Your are right about `(key,value)`. It is redundant here.

Comment: Interesting. As I mentioned, you actually don't need any unpacking anywhere. I would be curious about the timing results with `item` instead of `(key, value)` and `key=lambda item: item[1]`.

Comment: @EOL Unpacking actually happens here: `key_value, fter`. It is needed to apply filtering (I iterate through `my_list` and `my_lookup` simultaneously with `zip` and then unpack each pair into `key_value, fter`). (It is actually what `compress` does).

Comment: @EOL You write "your `value` is redundant since we already have `my_lookup` and `key`, so that `value = my_lookup[key]`". This `my_lookup[key]` makes dictionary lookup. When I iterate through ordered dictionary with `itertimes()` it is performed differently. The fact that using lookups turned out to be faster in the end is not very obvious without benchmarks.

Comment: @EOL By the way, it is very interesting performance issue. I [asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640235/understanding-performance-difference) to understand it better.

Comment: @EOF **nymk** gave a great anser [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17845560/862380). It turns out that dictionary lookup may be slower than packing and unpacking in the tuple (see the very end of his answer). Still, it only happens for ordinary dict and in the case when taking hash is complex enough to be more expensive than packing-unpacking into tuple. And in case of `OrderedDict` the solution with dictionary lookup is always faster because `OrderedDict` is implemented in such a way as `iteritems` invokes dictionary lookup for each value.

Comment: @EOF But I hope you see now that my solution couldn't be called suboptimal without the analysis made by **nymk**. It wasn't evident that `OrderedDict` performs dictionary lookups while iterating with `iteritems`. And in case of builting `dict` using `iteritems` may be faster.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing. This solution is adaptation of so called [`Decorate-Sort-Undecorate` pattern](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate). Here I decorated keys with values to determine `min ` by, and then took key corresponding to the minimum value.

Comment: And finally, now I know a new pattern with `key = dic.get`, which usually faster for (always for `OrderedDict` and often for common `dict`), which is also quite readable (which in case of Python is very important).

Comment: Thank you for the followup on speed issues. Note that I never intended to comment on the execution speed of your answer, but only on its programming style. To summarize, I meant that Python offers a simpler approach than the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate pattern, because it allows one to bypass explicit decorate and then undecorate actions. Thus, `min(…, key=…)` requires fewer cognitive steps to understand, and is therefore faster to *comprehend* (i.e. is more legible). Anyway, the execution speed discussion was interesting, thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Two-liner:

```
from itertools import izip
print min((lookup_key for (lookup_key, keep) in izip(my_lookup.iterkeys(),
            my_list) if keep), key=my_lookup.get)
```

Comment: This is a reimplementation of the existing standard `itertools.compress()`. I am all for Python programmers to use the efficient and standard tools offered by Python instead of reinventing the wheel with expressions that take longer to read and understand…

Comment: @EOL: Point taken, I agree -- totally forgot about `itertools.compress()` which was added to the module in 2.7/3.1...so perhaps this would be useful to folks still using earlier versions.

Comment: Good point. I rewrote your solution so as to make it a little more legible ("`keep`" has a more obvious meaning than `item[0]`, and I avoided doing `iteritems()` and naming `item` a variable which is *not* one of the items).

Comment: @EOL: Again, good points, so your edits are fine, except I also think avoiding long lines improves readability, esp here in SO's code boxes.

Comment: OK. Since only the keys are needed, I replaced `iteritems` by `iterkeys`, which makes `item[0]` unnecessary.

Comment: @EOL: All this back-n-forth only emphasizes why `itertools.compress()` is the way to go if it's available (and may be part of the reason why they added it ;-).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, a slight variation of the original code performs reasonably (on par with ovgolovin's approach) and is quite readable:

```
minimum = (None, float('inf'))
for i, item in enumerate(my_lookup.items()):
    if not my_list[i]:
        continue
    if item[1] < minimum[1]:
        minimum = item
return minimum[0]
```

Even the original code is only slightly slower than this, based on ovgolovin's ideone benchmark. Of course, Jared's solution is quite faster and quite shorter.

Comment: I really don't recommend that anybody uses this: it is much, much longer to read and comprehend than Jared's simple solution. One of the advantages of Python is that it allows one not to have to program like in C. :)

Comment: @EOL, I agree, Jared's solution is incredibly elegant. My point was just that shorter code, or one-liners, as the user asked, are not necessarily something to strive for. They should be the means and not the end.

Comment: Yeah, it's true that a few lines of code can be better than a single line. The goal should indeed be the legibility (speed of understanding) of the code. The problem with one-liners is that there are two kinds of one-liners: those created to do a lot in as few characters as possible, even if this sacrifices legibility, and those that are actually very legible because they use high-level, powerful  but standard tools. (Jared's very good solution arguably falls in the second category.)