# Understanding performance difference

Tags: python, python-2.7

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638308/finding-key-with-minimum-value-in-ordereddict) I faced an interesting situation 2 similar code snippets performed quite differently. I'm asking here just to understand the reason for that and to improve my intuition for such cases.

I'll adapt code snippets for Python 2.7 (In Python 3 the performance differences are the same).

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import izip

items = OrderedDict([('a', 10), ('b', 9), ('c', 4), ('d', 7), ('e', 3), ('f', 0), ('g', -5), ('h', 9)])

def f1():
    return min(items, key=items.get)

def f2():
    return min(items.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]


from timeit import Timer
N = 100000

print(Timer(stmt='f1()', setup='from __main__ import f1').timeit(number = N))
print(Timer(stmt='f2()', setup='from __main__ import f2').timeit(number = N))
```

Output:

```
0.603327797248
1.21580172899
```

The first solution has to make lookups in `OrderedDictionary` to get `value` for each `key`. Second solution just iterates through `OrderedDictionary` key-value pairs, which have to be packed into tuples.

The second solution is 2 times slower.

Why is that?

I recently watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OSGv2VnC0go#t=1367s), where Raymond Hettinger says that Python tends to reuse tuples, so no extra allocations.

So, what does this performance issue boil down to?

---

I want to elaborate a bit on why I'm asking.

The first solution has dictionary lookup. It implies taking `key` hash, then finding bin by this hash, then getting key from that bin (hopefully there will be no key collisions), and then getting value associated with that key.

The second solution just goes through all bins and yields all the keys in those bins. It goes through all the bins one-by-one without an overhead of calculation which bin to take. Yes, it has to access values associated with those keys, but the value is only one step from the key, while the first solution has to go through hash-bin-key-value chain to get the value when it needs it. Each solution has to get the value, the first one gets it through hash-bin-key-value chain, the second gets it following one more pointer when accessing key. The only overhead of the second solution is it has to store this value in the tuple temporary along with the key. It turns out that this storing is the major reason for the overhead. Still I don't fully understand why is it so, given the fact there is so-called "tuple reuse" (see the video mentioned above).

To my mind, the second solution has to save value along with the key, but it avoid us of having to make hash-bin-key calculation and access to get value for that key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The performance differences is mainly caused by `OrderedDict`. 
`OrderedDict` uses `dict`'s `get` and `__getitem__`, but redefined its own [`__iter__`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/collections.py#l73) and [`iteritems`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/collections.py#l121).

```
    def __iter__(self):
        'od.__iter__()  iter(od)'
        # Traverse the linked list in order.
        root = self.__root
        curr = root[1]                                  # start at the first node
        while curr is not root:
            yield curr[2]                               # yield the curr[KEY]
            curr = curr[1]                              # move to next node

    def iteritems(self):
        'od.iteritems -> an iterator over the (key, value) pairs in od'
        for k in self:
            yield (k, self[k])
```

Look at what we found: `self[k]`.
Your second solution did not help us avoid the hash-bin-key calculation.
While the iterator generated by `dict`, more precisely, [`items.iteritems().next()`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Objects/dictobject.c#l2668) if `items` is a `dict`, does not make that calculation.

Moreover, `iteritems` is also more expensive.

```
from timeit import Timer
N = 1000

d = {i:i for i in range(10000)}

def f1():
    for k in d: pass

def f2():
    for k in d.iterkeys(): pass

def f3():
    for v in d.itervalues(): pass

def f4():
    for t in d.iteritems(): pass

print(Timer(stmt='f1()', setup='from __main__ import f1').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f2()', setup='from __main__ import f2').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f3()', setup='from __main__ import f3').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f4()', setup='from __main__ import f4').timeit(number=N))
```

Output

```
0.256800375467
0.265079360645
0.260599391822
0.492333103788
```

Comparing to `iterkeys`' [`dictiter_iternextkey`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Objects/dictobject.c#l2524) and `itervalues`' [`dictiter_iternextvalue`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Objects/dictobject.c#l2596), `iteritems`'[`dictiter_iternextitem`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Objects/dictobject.c#l2668) has additional parts.

```
    if (result->ob_refcnt == 1) {
        Py_INCREF(result);
        Py_DECREF(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(result, 0));
        Py_DECREF(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(result, 1));
    } else {
        result = PyTuple_New(2);
        if (result == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }
    di->len--;
    key = ep[i].me_key;
    value = ep[i].me_value;
    Py_INCREF(key);
    Py_INCREF(value);
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(result, 0, key);
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(result, 1, value);
```

I think that tuple creation could decrease the performance.

Python indeed tends to reuse tuples.
[`tupleobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Objects/tupleobject.c#l5) shows

```
/* Speed optimization to avoid frequent malloc/free of small tuples */
#ifndef PyTuple_MAXSAVESIZE
#define PyTuple_MAXSAVESIZE     20  /* Largest tuple to save on free list */
#endif
#ifndef PyTuple_MAXFREELIST
#define PyTuple_MAXFREELIST  2000  /* Maximum number of tuples of each size to save */
#endif
```

This optimization just means Python does not build some tuples from scratch. But there is still a lot of work to be done.

---

#### Case: dict

If `OrderedDict` is replaced by `dict`, I think the second solution is slightly better in general. 
Python dictionaries are implemented using hash tables. So the lookup is fast. The average time complexity of lookup is O(1), while the worst is O(n)<sup>1</sup>.
The average time complexity of your first solution is the same as the time complexity of your second solution. They are both O(n).
Therefore, the second solution has no advantages or is even slower sometimes, especially when the input data is small.
In that case, the extra cost caused by `iteritems` could not be compensated.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter
from timeit import Timer
from random import randint, random

N = 100000
xs = [('a', 10), ('b', 9), ('c', 4), ('d', 7), ('e', 3), ('f', 0), ('g', -5), ('h', 9)]

od = OrderedDict(xs)
d = dict(xs)

def f1od_min():
    return min(od, key=od.get)

def f2od_min():
    return min(od.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]

def f1d_min():
    return min(d, key=d.get)

def f2d_min():
    return min(d.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]

def f1od():
    for k in od: pass

def f2od():
    for t in od.iteritems(): pass

def f1d():
    for k in d: pass

def f2d():
    for t in d.iteritems(): pass

print 'min'
print(Timer(stmt='f1od_min()', setup='from __main__ import f1od_min').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f2od_min()', setup='from __main__ import f2od_min').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f1d_min()', setup='from __main__ import f1d_min').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f2d_min()', setup='from __main__ import f2d_min').timeit(number=N))
print
print 'traverse'
print(Timer(stmt='f1od()', setup='from __main__ import f1od').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f2od()', setup='from __main__ import f2od').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f1d()', setup='from __main__ import f1d').timeit(number=N))
print(Timer(stmt='f2d()', setup='from __main__ import f2d').timeit(number=N))
```

Output

```
min
0.398274431527
0.813040903243
0.185168156847
0.249574387248    <-- dict/the second solution

traverse
0.251634216081
0.642283865687
0.0565099754298
0.0958057518483
```

Then replace `N` and `xs` by

```
N = 50
xs = [(x, randint(1, 100)) for x in range(100000)]
```

Output

```
min
1.5148923257
3.47020082161
0.712828585756
0.70823812803    <-- dict/the second solution

traverse
0.975989336634
2.92283956481
0.127676073356
0.253622387762
```

Now replace `N` and `xs` by

```
N = 10
xs = [(random(), random()) for x in range(1000000)]
```

Output

```
min
6.23311265817
10.702984667
4.32852708934
2.87853889251    <-- dict/the second solution

traverse
2.06231783648
9.49360449443
1.33297618831
1.73723008092
```

Finally, the second solution starts to shine.

---

The worse case for the first solution: **hash collision**

Let

```
N = 10000
xs = [(2 ** (32 + x) - 2 ** x + 1, 1) for x in range(100)]
# hash(2 ** (32 + x) - 2 ** x + 1) is always 1
```

Output

```
min
2.44175265292    <-- lookup is slow
2.76424538594    <-- lookup is slow
2.26508627493    <-- lookup is slow
0.199363955475

traverse
0.200654482623
2.59635966303    <-- lookup is slow
0.0454684184722
0.0733798569371
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The Average Case times listed for dict objects assume that the hash function for the objects is sufficiently robust to make collisions uncommon. The Average Case assumes the keys used in parameters are selected uniformly at random from the set of all keys. See [TimeComplexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Is second solution faster for `xs = [(random(), random()) for x in range(1000000)]` because taking hash for float is slower (while for int hash is usually int itself)?

Comment: @ovgolovin, you're right. It is calculating hash values that made the first solution slower in this case. Hash collision would make the first solution slower as well.

Comment: Thanks! I thinks `OrderedDict` may be implemented in a better way: not by subclassing `dict`, but by having `dict` and `list of sublists`, with `dict` mapping `key` to `sublist in list`, each `sublist` containing `key-value` pairs. Then iteration can be done without dictionary lookups just by traversing `list`. And it would rather be implemented in C, thus avoiding keeping keys both in `dict` and as first elements in `list`, as bin may be pointing directly to [key,value] sublists in `list` instead of `key`.

Answer (score 3):

For tuple reuse, I don't believe it:

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> b = (1,2)
>>> id(a)
139912909456232
>>> id(b)
139912909456304
>>>
```

You can see from int or string:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> id(a)
34961336
>>> id(b)
34961336
>>> 
>>> a = 'a'
>>> b = 'a'
>>> id(a)
139912910202240
>>> id(b)
139912910202240
>>>
```

**edit:**

For `dict`, your two methods are similar. Let's try:

```
>>> a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> N = 100000
# really quick to use []
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a: z = a[x]', setup='from __main__ import a').timeit(number=N)
0.0524289608001709
# use get method
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a: z = a.get(x)', setup='from __main__ import a').timeit(number=N)
0.10028195381164551
# use iterator and []
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a.iteritems(): z = x[1]', setup='from __main__ import a').timeit(number=N)
0.08019709587097168
# use itemgetter and iterator
>>> b = itemgetter(1)
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a.iteritems(): z = b(x)', setup='from __main__ import a, b').timeit(number=N)
0.09941697120666504
```

Though the time may change, but they are accurate in general. Using `iteritems` and `itemgetter` is as quick as `get`.

But for `OrderedDict`, let's try again:

```
>>> a
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)])
>>> N = 100000
#Use []
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a: z = a[x]', setup='from __main__ import a').timeit(number=N)
0.2354598045349121
#Use get
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a: z = a.get(x)', setup='from __main__ import a').timeit(number=N)
0.21950387954711914
#Use iterator
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a.iteritems(): z = x[1]', setup='from __main__ import a').timeit(number=N)
0.29949188232421875
#Use iterator and itemgetter
>>> b = itemgetter(1)
>>> Timer(stmt='for x in a.iteritems(): z = b(x)', setup='from __main__ import a, b').timeit(number=N)
0.32039499282836914
```

You can see that, for `OrderedDict`, Use `get` and the one use `iterator` and `itemgetter` vary in time.

So, I think the time difference is because the implementation of `OrderedDict`. But sorry I don't know why.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably easier to see than trying to explain it in words. +1

Comment: The fact that `f2` code is longer doesn't mean it has to be executed longer. Because a lot from those commands are invoked only once. About reuse. I think it happens inside functions written in C (dict, min, etc.), but it is just guessing, I would like to learn about it if there is somebody to explain it (Raymond Hettinger is the person to write a lot of core Python data structures, and if the says there is reuse, I think there is, because he knows internals very well).

Comment: I know the length doesn't mean the excuting time. But from my point of view, I can see `f2` is slower. More function calls, more operations. And about the reuse, I just believe the result I get. In CPython, [`id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) returns the address of the object in memory. If they are the same one, the result should be the same.@ovgolovin

Comment: I have updated my answer. May be of some help. Hope you can check. @ovgolovin

Comment: The disassembly is completely meaningless, because the real work will happen inside the call to `min`, which you can't see there. All the disassembly shows is setup stuff - it doesn't have any loops.

Comment: Thanks! I think your investigation sheds light on what is happening there.

Comment: If we use `dict` instead of `OrderedDict` time difference still exists , still not that dramatic (0.243047929276 and 0.327879101953 on my computer). My only guess is that storing to the tuple takes longer than retrieving from dictionary by key.

Comment: Also, there still maybe tuple allocation on each iteration in second solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you yourself mentioned, there is a difference between the functions.

Where the first function iterates over a list of strings, for each string it goes to the dictionary and looks it up to get the value, then it finds the minimum and returns.

The second function iterates over tuples of string/int pairs. and then for each one it accesses the second item (the int/value) and then it finds the minimum, (which is a tuple in this case) and then it returns that results first item.

The second function is doing a lot more work, on objects that require a lot more processing, (tuples > strings) and then (tuples > ints) , plus the additional item retrieval.

Why are you surprised?

Comment: I'm surprised of 2 times difference. I thought these snippets should have similar performance. Because lookup in the dictionary is not that simple (bin should be found, than keys corresponding to that bin, then value for fitting key). When we iterate over dictionary key-value pairs, there is no search for bin and then key in it, we just go through all bins and all keys in them. But second solution has an overhead of having to put key-value into tuple, and than get second value from tuple back (which is random access), but I didn't expect it to give such huge overhead.

Comment: What object to you mean? Did you watch video about tuple reuse? I just asked this question because I don't fully understand all the steps Python takes in each code case, so I expected somebody to be able to explain all this in detail. From the first glance (without benchmarking) I thought that first solution is slower as it has to make dictionary lookups, and second just has to store key-values into the same tuple.

Comment: [zhangyangyu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2189957/zhangyangyu)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17640469/1561176) resolves your technical questions.

Comment: @ovgolovin It is not just 2 times. Try giving a bigger dictionary and see the difference. Using iterator will add O(n) time complexity, so the gap between timings will keep on increasing as number of items in dict increases.

Comment: In Python 3 `.items()` will give iterator like `.iteritems()` in 2.7, so performance will be same.

Comment: @user568109 It's a good point about size of the dictionary. As regards iterator addin `O(n)` time complexity, I'm not getting it. `min(items, key=items.get)` has `O(n)` complexity, as it goes through all the items. `min(items.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]` has also `O(n)` complexity as it goes through the same items, packed into key-value pairs by `iteritems` generator. The difference is about constants.

Comment: @user568109 What I really expect from the question is to get the rule of the thumb which operations I should prefer when writing code snippets. Both solutions in the question are nearly equal in terms of readability (at least for me), so I want to be able to understood at first glance which one will be faster and prefer it over the other option.

Comment: @ovgolovin Yes adding two O(n) time would mean only change in coefficient of n in O(n), as access time per key-value is increased. The time difference between the two methods increases with n.

Comment: @user568109 Second solution not only adds to this coefficient, but save us of need to access value in the dictionary by key, because it iterates through key-value pairs consecutively, while the first one iterates through keys, but has to retrieve value via dictionary lookup (which implies taking hash and other operations), the second solution only has to store value in the tuple. So it is not correct to say that the second solution has increased coefficient: it has different coefficient, and it is not obvious at the first glance if it is bigger or smaller.

Comment: @ovgolovin the dictionary exists for both methods. You are trivialising the time taken for iterator to return a key-value pair. It also will have to lookup the value to return a key-value pair. After all what you are giving the iterator is dictionary. What iterator does different from first is that it defers giving the next key-value in loop until asked(lazy evaluation), whereas first method gives all values at once. Second method adds processing and copying to the lookup, so it will have higher coefficient.

Comment: @user568109 If you know how hash-map works, you should see that there is no need to lookup the key while iteration through hash-map, because you just iterate through all the bins and return keys and associated values (while key lookup takes it to calculate hash on it to get bin number and only then access that key in that bin, and after that access the value associated with it). Surely, `iteritems` may be implemented as to make lookups, but that would be insane to implement it this way as to calculate bin again while you are already in that bin.

Comment: @user568109 First method doesn't give all values at once, as `min` uses it as iterator (it invokes `__iter__` method of it and goes through it value by value). In this sense the solutions are alike as they traverse the dictionary lazily.

Comment: @user568109 Second solution definitely forms a tuple from key-value pair on each iteration. But if there is tuple reuse (as in CPython), the tuple is not allocated, it is taken from previously disposed. So it comes down to just storing key and value to existing tuple taken from disposed. I expect saving two values to be pretty fast. The first solution has to invoke `hash` to determine bin. Are you sure that saving 2 values to tuple is slower than calculation hash and accessing bin?

Comment: @ovgolovin I was comparing items vs iterator items.iteritems(). Yes min being an iterator will not give all values, but i was not refering to min. I was refering to the difference in the first arguments. The first has all the values, the second requires extra processing to get the values.

Comment: You guys should really move this conversation to a chat.

Comment: ... If you did move it to a chat, you should include the link here for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17640334/1561176). To get a better view of what is happening, you can always use the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f1)
              0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (min)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (items)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('key')
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (items)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                2 (get)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION          257
             18 RETURN_VALUE    
>>> dis.dis(f2)
              0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (min)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (items)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                2 (iteritems)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('key')
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (itemgetter)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 CALL_FUNCTION          257
             27 LOAD_CONST               3 (0)
             30 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, there is a lot more happening in `f2` (and therefore it would stand to reason that it is slower)

You can always use the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module to check anything in Python, it usually gives a great indication of what will perform better.

---

One can always use the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module to check the timing or performance of certain methods or functions as they perform on specific types of input, but sometimes the timing can be off because the sample set of data being used is more suited to a certain function than another, for instance, when checking a sorting function, a list that is most sorted already would favor a certain type of function over another which may be faster to sort a less sorted list, but none of these take into account different types of data that might be inside the lists themselves. Using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module avoids most of that by being able to see directly what Python is doing behind the curtain (or under the hood) which gives a much clearer indicator on which method might be best suited to perform certain tasks