# Index duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list, for instance `list = [1,5,6,8,1,9]`

I want the index of the smallest value, and after coding, it will show me `0` but the problem is the `1` is appearing twice. Can  someone explain me how my program could show `4` instead of `0`?

To make it clearer if I have a number `k` and my `k` is appearing `x` times in my list, I want that my program shows the index of the last `k` in the list (with `k` being the smallest value of the list).

Here is my code:

```
z=int(input())
a=0
y=[]
for loop in range(z):
    a=int(input())
    y.append(a)
print(y.index(min(y))+1)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17952612/3001761

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will look at it. The problem is that i'm new at coding on python so i don't this command "dict'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_last_index(seq):
    return (len(seq)-1) - seq[::-1].index(min(seq))
```

Given:

```
lst = [1,5,6,8,1,9]
```

...

```
>>> lst = [1,5,6,8,1,9]
>>> get_last_index(lst)
4
```

The code simply reverses the list, retrieves the index of the `item` and takes that away from the total length of the list minus one for zero-indexability.

Comment: Ops, didn't notice you wanted smallest value-- let me re-adjust my code to account for that

Answer (score 2):

There could be better answer

```
[i for i,j in enumerate(list) if j==min(list)]
[0, 4]
```

Comment: And what if it appears three times, or the first appearance isn't the first element?

Answer (score 0):

This will get the last index of the smallest value.

```
lst = [1,5,6,8,1,9]
[c for c,e in enumerate(lst) if e==min(lst)][-1]
```